# Error in if (nrow(chan) == 0) { : argument is of length zero in slackr Package

Tags: r, alert, slack, slackr

I am currently trying to create a slack - R integration to create an alert when specific rules / threshold is hit. I'm using slackr package (v. 2.1.0)

The only function that is working right now is only `slackr::slackr_bot` as it successfully send a bot message into the private channels.

```
start <- paste0("Start checking the anomaly")
slackr::slackr_bot(start, incoming_webhook_url=whurl )
```

and it return a slack notifications below:
[image: slack notifications successfully sent]

When I am trying to set the initial `slackr_setup` with below command (I believe it is needed for more functions like sending image, post) it keep getting error. Below are the script used:

```
slackr::slackr_setup(channel = "test_slack_alert_mn", 
                    username = '@Alert System',
                    icon_emoji = "",
                    incoming_webhook_url = whurl, #variable from slack app
                    bot_user_oauth_token  = apitk, #oauth_token from slack app
                    echo = FALSE
                    )
```

This is the error message:

```
Error in if (nrow(chan) == 0) { : argument is of length zero
```

Do you guys know what happen here and what should I do to solve this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm experiencing the same issue.

I can add that this is a problem that appeared very recently.

A Shiny App I developed months ago relies on slackr & gmailR to send notifications to the admin.

It started to fail on the slackr_setup with exactly the same error `Error in if (nrow(chan) == 0) {` on last deployment a few days ago.

I just fixed it by installing the latest dev version on github !

`devtools::install_github("mrkaye97/slackr")`

I think the fix came from [this commit](https://github.com/mrkaye97/slackr/commit/ab29b8a77ec0696fb1718d7d813eb7a0241a94c2) where `if(nrow(chan)==0)` was replaced by `if(is.null(chan)||nrow(chan)==0)`